# Recursive merge of N level maps

Tags: java

Is there a way to deep a deep merge of maps in Java? I've seen a couple posts about it but most seem solutions seem to only deal with one level of merging or are of tedious.

My data structure (using a JSON string to represent the map) looks something similar to this:

```
{ name: "bob", emails: { home: "bob@home.com", work : "bob@work.com" } }
```

Ideally if I have another map like

```
{ emails: { home2: "bob@home2.com" } }
```

post merge with the first map it would look something like

```
{ name: "bob", emails: { home: "bob@home.com", work : "bob@work.com", home2: "bob@home2.com } }
```

I can guarantee all of my Maps are of `<String, Object>`. Is there an out of the box solution to this? Really am trying to avoid self writing a bunch of recursive or iterative code for very nested or large objects.

Comment: What happens if there are conflicts?  How do you want that handled?  Good question by the way.

Comment: For myself, it's left to right map merge, right map (new map) overrides old map if the key exists....

Answer (score 20):

Improved version of: [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aslakhellesoy/3858814)

Here is a way to deep merge Java Maps:

```
// This is fancier than Map.putAll(Map)
private static Map deepMerge(Map original, Map newMap) {
    for (Object key : newMap.keySet()) {
        if (newMap.get(key) instanceof Map && original.get(key) instanceof Map) {
            Map originalChild = (Map) original.get(key);
            Map newChild = (Map) newMap.get(key);
            original.put(key, deepMerge(originalChild, newChild));
        } else if (newMap.get(key) instanceof List && original.get(key) instanceof List) {
            List originalChild = (List) original.get(key);
            List newChild = (List) newMap.get(key);
            for (Object each : newChild) {
                if (!originalChild.contains(each)) {
                    originalChild.add(each);
                }
            }
        } else {
            original.put(key, newMap.get(key));
        }
    }
    return original;
}
```

Works for nested maps, objects, and lists of objects. Enjoy.

(Disclaimer: I am no Java developer!)

Answer (score 6):

I am using [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to load json and [yaml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml) configuration files, there is a base configuration file and one configuration file for each environment.
I load the base config and the environment specific config.
Then I deep merge both maps. Lists are also merged, removing duplicates.
Values are deep merged on map1 and values from map2 override values from map1 in case of collisions.

```
void deepMerge(Map<String, Object> map1, Map<String, Object> map2) {
    for(String key : map2.keySet()) {
        Object value2 = map2.get(key);
        if (map1.containsKey(key)) {
            Object value1 = map1.get(key);
            if (value1 instanceof Map && value2 instanceof Map) 
                deepMerge((Map<String, Object>) value1, (Map<String, Object>) value2);
            else if (value1 instanceof List && value2 instanceof List) 
                map1.put(key, merge((List) value1, (List) value2));
            else map1.put(key, value2);
        } else map1.put(key, value2);
    }
}

List merge(List list1, List list2) {
    list2.removeAll(list1);
    list1.addAll(list2);
    return list1;
}
```

For example:
Base config:

```
electronics:
  computers:
    laptops:
      apple:
        macbook: 1000
        macbookpro: 2000
      windows:
        surface: 2000
    desktop:
      apple:
        imac: 1000
      windows:
        surface: 2000
  phones:
    android:
      samsung:
        motox: 300
    apple:
      iphone7: 500

books:
  technical:
    - java
    - perl
  novels:
    - guerra y paz
    - crimen y castigo
  poetry:
    - neruda
    - parra
```

test env config:

```
electronics:
  computers:
    laptops:
      windows:
        surface: 2500
    desktop: 100
  phones:
    windows:
      nokia: 800

books:
  technical:
    - f sharp
  novels: [2666]
  poetry:
    - parra
```

merged config:

```
electronics:
  computers:
    laptops:
      apple:
        macbook: 1000
        macbookpro: 2000
      windows:
        surface: 2500
    desktop: 100
  phones:
    android:
      samsung:
        motox: 300
    apple:
      iphone7: 500
    windows:
      nokia: 800
books:
  technical:
  - "java"
  - "perl"
  - "f sharp"
  novels:
  - "guerra y paz"
  - "crimen y castigo"
  - 2666
  poetry:
  - "neruda"
  - "parra"
```

Answer (score 6):

I recentlty had to do something similar, but i wanted a solution:

- with java8
- that wouldn't modify the original maps and so would return a new map

The merge method does the actual merge, it starts with getting a copy of the original map and recursively merges nested maps and collections.

If there are key collisions and the associated values are not a Map or a Collection, values from Map b are given the priority.

```
public static Map merge(Map a, Map b) {
    if (a == null && b == null)
        return null;
    if (a == null || a.size() == 0)
        return copy(b);
    if (b == null || b.size() == 0)
        return copy(a);
    Map copy = copy(a);
    copy.putAll(
        (Map) b
            .keySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                    key -> key,
                    key -> {
                        Object original = copy.get(key);
                        Object value = b.get(key);
                        if (value == null && original == null)
                            return null;
                        if (value == null && original != null)
                            return original;
                        if (value != null && original == null)
                            return value;
                        if (value instanceof Map && original instanceof Map)
                            return merge((Map) original, (Map) value);
                        else if (value instanceof Collection
                            && original instanceof Collection) {
                            try {
                                Collection merge =
                                    newCollectionInstance(
                                        (Collection) original,
                                        (List) Lists
                                            .newArrayList(
                                                (Collection) original,
                                                (Collection) value)
                                            .stream()
                                            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
                                return merge;
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
                        return value;
                    })));
    return copy;
}
```

Here is the method to copy a map

```
public static Map copy(Map original) {
    return (Map) original
        .keySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                key -> key,
                key -> {
                    Object value = original.get(key);
                    if (value instanceof Map)
                        return copy((Map) value);
                    if (value instanceof Collection)
                        return newCollectionInstance((Collection) value, (Collection) value);
                    return value;
                }));
}
```

and a helper method to copy a Collection with the same type

```
public static Collection newCollectionInstance(Collection collection, Collection elements) {
    try {
        Collection newInstance = collection.getClass().newInstance();
        newInstance.addAll(elements);
        return newInstance;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `collection.getClass().newInstance().addAll(elements);` - what if collection is unidentifiable? For example, `Set.of (1, 2, 4)` and you copy it your way? Anyway, well done!

Answer (score 2):

I really like wonderkid2's approach above.

I modified it a bit more:

1. slightly higher performance (avoiding some .get(_) calls by using Entry)
2. recurse on any Collection, not just Lists
3. some stricter validations

This isn't a wonderful approach in general, but I see how it might be needed sometimes.

(p.s. I use Guava, but those calls (Objects.equals, Preconditions.checkArgument) are easy to replace if necessary.)

```
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
static void deepMerge(
        Map original,
        Map newMap) {

    for (Entry e : (Set<Entry>) newMap.entrySet()) {
        Object
            key = e.getKey(),
            value = e.getValue();

        // unfortunately, if null-values are allowed,
        // we suffer the performance hit of double-lookup
        if (original.containsKey(key)) {
            Object originalValue = original.get(key);

            if (Objects.equal(originalValue, value))
                return;

            if (originalValue instanceof Collection) {
                // this could be relaxed to simply to simply add instead of addAll
                // IF it's not a collection (still addAll if it is),
                // this would be a useful approach, but uncomfortably inconsistent, algebraically
                Preconditions.checkArgument(value instanceof Collection,
                        "a non-collection collided with a collection: %s%n\t%s",
                        value, originalValue);

                ((Collection) originalValue).addAll((Collection) value);

                return;
            }

            if (originalValue instanceof Map) {
                Preconditions.checkArgument(value instanceof Map,
                        "a non-map collided with a map: %s%n\t%s",
                        value, originalValue);

                deepMerge((Map) originalValue, (Map) value);

                return;
            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
                    "collision detected: %s%n%\torig:%s",
                    value, originalValue));

        } else
            original.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `return` in each `if` statement, it should be `continue`. And if you want to overwrite existing keys in the `original` map (instead of throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`, replace the `IllegalArgumentException` with `original.put(key, value);`.

Answer (score -2):

There's no deep merge method that I'm aware of, but this is likely by design.  In general, nested `Map`s are an anti-pattern since they quickly become unmanageable.  For example, suppose you're handed a piece of code that looks like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> someNonsensicalMap = someObject.getNonsensicalMap();
```

Good luck making much sense of what that map contains without a time-consuming reverse-engineering effort.  This kind of thing should be avoided.

The common idiom to remedy this is to use a class instead of a nested map to give the contents some meaningful context.  One real-world example of this comes into play when parsing XML with the DOM.  Have a look at the answer to this SO post:  [parsing Xml with NodeList and DocumentBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604876/parsing-xml-with-nodelist-and-documentbuilder) .  You can see that instead of nested maps, there's a `NodeList` object, which contains `Element`s, which can themselves contain `NodeList`s, etc.  That's easier to follow and allows virtually infinite nesting.

So I would strongly recommend revisiting your design and avoid nested maps.  When using classes instead of a nested map, then you can add a merge method or methods to your class to perform the deep merge:

```
class Person {
  Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
  Set<String> emails = new HashSet<String>();

  public Set<String> getNames() { return names; }
  public Set<String> getEmails() { return emails; }

  public void mergeNames(HashSet<String> moreNames) {
    names.addAll(moreNames);
  }

  public void mergeEmails(HashSet<String> moreEmails) {
    emails.addAll(moreEmails);
  }

  public void mergeNames(HashSet<String> moreNames) {
    names.addAll(moreNames);
  }

  public void mergePerson(Person person) {
    mergeNames(person.getNames());
    mergeEmails(person.getEmails());
  }
}
```

The above is kind of a trivial example based on your JSON above, but can easily be extended to recursively merge whatever fields the class contains.

Comment: I would agree with you except there is a flaw about having to reconstruct the data if you need it in nested map form. That could be a problem.

Comment: Can you give an example of why you would ever need it in nested map form?  Do you mean that the map would need to be serialized/deserialized to JSON or XML?  Because this can also be handled by adding a toJSON() and/or toXML() method to the class, rather than using the nested map antipattern.