# Java XML: parsing nested XML file with identical tags

Tags: java, xml, dom

#### Background

I have an XML document that represents a data structure in LabVIEW (an array of clusters of clusters) that stores simulation parameters. I generated the document by saving my data structure as XML from LabVIEW, and I need to keep its general format so that LabVIEW can read it back at a later time. The document is structured as follows:

```xml
<Array>
    <Cluster>
        <Name>Meaningful Name 1</Name>
        <Cluster>  <!-- note clusters within clusters -->
            <Name>Component 1 params</Name>
            <!-- Parameter values here -->
        </Cluster>
        <Cluster>
            <Name>Component 2 params</Name>
            <!-- Parameter values here -->
        </Cluster>
    </Cluster>
    <!-- More clusters of clusters -->
</Array>
```

Each parent `Cluster` will have exactly the same child elements (Component 1 params, Component 2 params, etc.), only their `Value` fields (not shown) will be different. Each parent `Cluster` will also have a unique name. I cannot change the tags used to specify the parent/child clusters because then LabVIEW will not read the file.

#### Work so far

I am working on a Java app to allow users to edit the parameter data stored in the document without breaking its format (so that LabVIEW can still read it). I want the user to be able to select one of the parent clusters by its `Name` field, and then populate a form with the data stored within so that this data can be edited. My problem is that using the [`DocumentBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) and [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) classes, I cannot seem to split out only the parent `Cluster` nodes.

Working from the answer to [parsing XML with NodeList and DocumentBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604876/parsing-xml-with-nodelist-and-documentbuilder):

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = builder.parse("param_file.xml");

NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Cluster");  // every Cluster is in this list, but I only want to iterate over the top-level clusters.
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); ++i)
{
    Element node = (Element) nodes.item(i);
    // Display the cluster names for the user to select one...
}
```

#### Question

I guess I am looking for a way to represent my XML file as an object that maintains the tree structure and then generate a list of only the top-level `Cluster` elements, which can then each be drilled into to get/set their child `Cluster` elements and the attributes thereof.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Document` instance already represents the tree structure of the XML in memory. You'll have to navigate your way properly through this structure. If you want the top-level `Cluster` elements, you can get the child nodes of the root of the XML and loop over them:

```
List<Node> topLevelClusterElements = new ArrayList<Node>();

NodeList childNodes = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
for(int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node childNode = childNodes.item(i);
    if(childNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && childNode.getNodeName().equals("Cluster")) {
        Element clusterElement = (Element) childNode;
        topLevelClusterElements.add(clusterElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Where is the documentation for whatever `doc.getDocumentElement()` returns? Looking at the documentation for [`Element`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html), there does not seem to be a `getChildNodes()` method, thus my continued confusion. Thanks again!

Comment: Never mind, I got it. `getChildNodes()` is a method of the parent class [`Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).

Comment: Hang on, does this still grab every `Cluster` node and add it to the `topLevelClusterElements` list, or does it only grab the top-level `Cluster` nodes? Basically does `getChildNodes` only go down one level, or is it recursive and returns every child node?

Comment: No it's one level only, no recursion.